# Regular Expressions, Checking for a range of occurrences

Tags: regex

I have a phone number I want to match against a regular expression.
The format of the phone number must match this:

(123) 123-4567 x12345

The extension is optional. Also the extension must contain 1-5 numbers.
Below is a regular expression I wrote that works.

```
^\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}( x\d\d?\d?\d?\d?)?$
```

I was wondering if there is a better way to check for the extension instead of

```
x\d\d?\d?\d?\d?
```

Can I say 1-5 occurrences of \d instead of the above some how ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use this :

```
\d{1,5}
```

Check Limiting Repetitions paragraph on [this link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

`\d{1,5}` will check for between 1 and 5 occurences